# how to change property value of scoped service at configure method of startup.cs file in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm going to change or insert some value to my scoped service at startup.cs file.

This is my code.

I'm insert a value to MyService.SomeData property. but, In the view page, print empty value.

Why is that?

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        .
        .
        .
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            .
            .
            .
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
            var MyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
            app.Use(async (context, next) => 
            {
                if (context.Request.Query.ContainKey("conditionKey") && context.Request.Query["conditonKey"] == "something")
                {
                    MyService.SomeData = "foo";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Service
{
    public class MyService
    {
        public string SomeData { get; set; } = "";
    {
}
```

**MyView.cshtml**

```
@inject MyProject.Service.MyService MyService
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>@MyService.SomeData</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's scoped, every scope will get a new instance, so that won't work. Either register the service with a factory method, or inject a configuration type as another service dependency.

Comment: Thanks to your answer Jeremy.

Comment: yap i'm going to use new instance. so, i modified my code. The data was inserted on app.Use() lambda. but it's same.

Comment: @Jang-HoBae you are creating MyService outside of Use, it should be inside

Comment: @Jang-HoBae I updated my answer to use `app.Use()`

Comment: @YegorAndrosov Thanks to your advise, I solved it. Creating Request scoped Service in `app.Use()` middleware is right. And, Create by `context.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core pipeline creates scope per http request, so you need to set this property inside of your action method

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyService myService;

    public HomeController(MyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        myService.MyData = "MyData";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Or register your service as a singleton

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
    var MyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>();

    MyService.MyData = "SomeData";
}
```

Or register custom filter and integrate it into pipeline

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(x => x.Filters.Add(typeof(MyServiceFilter)));

    services.AddScoped<MyService>();
}


public class MyServiceFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly MyService myService;

    public MyServiceFilter(MyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        myService.MyData = "MyData";
    }
}
```

Finally, using `app.Use`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("conditionKey") && context.Request.Query["conditionKey"] == "something")
    {
        var myService = context.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();

        myService.MyData = "foo";
    }

    await next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer Yegor~. yap i'm going to use new instance. so, i modified my code. The data was inserted on app.Use() lambda. but it's same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @YegorAndrosov, I solved it.
Create Request scoped Service in app.Use() middleware. And, Create it by context.RequestServices.GetService();

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        .
        .
        .
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            .
            .
            .
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        }
        .
        .
        .
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            .
            .
            .
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var RequestData = context.RequestServices.GetService<RequestData>();
                var HompageSetting = context.RequestServices.GetService<HomepageSetting>();
                if (context.Request.Query.ContainKey("conditionKey") && context.Request.Query["conditonKey"] == "something")
                {
                    MyService.SomeData = "foo";
                }
                await next();
            });
        }
    }
}
```